# How to get childs key with snapshotChanges() AngularFire

Tags: firebase, angularfire, angularfire2

For example we have a database structure like:

under messagedata:

```
   authkey

       ----msgkey

           username:test
           message:test message
       ----msgkey2
           username:test
           message:test messagee
```

or we have db without authkey just msgkey like:

messagedata

```
   ---msgkey
       username:testuser
       message:test message
```

how to get message from database with its msgkey ?

in documentation code is

```
 afDb.object('items/1').snapshotChanges().map(action => {
    const $key = action.payload.key;
    const data = { $key, ...action.payload.val() };
    return data;
  }).subscribe(item => console.log(item.$key));
}
```

but in this code item.$key returns messagedata.i guess  somehow i need to go down 2 more layers 1 for authkey 1 for msgkey  or in second example 1 layer just to get msgkey ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi seems like you are doing minor mistake in your above code.

Your code should be like this :

```
afDb.object('items/1').snapshotChanges().map(action => {
const $key = action.key;
const data = { $key, $value: action.payload.val() };
return data;}).subscribe(item => {
console.log(item.$key);
console.log(item.value);});
```

The change made here is, instead of using `action.payload.key` 
 , `action.key` is used.

`action.key` holds the key of that particular action and to get the value , we use `action.payload.val()`